# Why Increment Pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I just recently started learning C++, and as most people (according to what I have been reading) I'm struggling with pointers.

Not in the traditional sense, I understand what they are, and why they are used, and how can they be useful, however I can't understand how incrementing pointers would be useful, can anyone provide an explanation of how incrementing a pointer is a useful concept and idiomatic C++?

This question came after I started reading the book [A Tour of C++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321958314) by Bjarne Stroustrup, I was recommended this book, because I'm quite familiar with Java, and the guys over at Reddit told me that it would be a good 'switchover' book.

Comment: A pointer is just an iterator

Comment: It's one of the favourite tools to write computer viruses that read what they should not read. It's also one of the most common cases of vulnerability in apps (when one increments a pointer past the area where they are supposed to, then reads or writes it)> See the HeartBleed bug.

Comment: @vasile This is what is **bad** about pointers.

Comment: @vasile I know pointers are used in malicious ways, but wouldn't the access of unauthorized memory cause a segfault? And wasn't the heartbleed bug also due to openssl having its own memory manager?

Comment: The nice/bad thing about C++ is that it allows you to do much more before calling a segfault. Usually you get a segfault when trying to access another process' memory, system memory or protected app memory. Any access inside the usual application pages is allowed by the system, and it's down to the programmer/compiler/language to enforce reasonable limits. C++ pretty much allows you to do whatever you want. As for openssl having its own memory manager - that's not true. It just has the default C++ memory access mechanisms.

Comment: @INdek: You'll only get a segfault if the memory you're trying to access is protected. Most operating systems assign protection at the page level, so you can usually access anything that's on the page your pointer starts on. If the OS uses a 4K page size, that's a fair amount of data. If your pointer starts out somewhere in the heap, it's anybody's guess how much data you could access.

Comment: @vasile: that's like saying that a hammer is one of the favorite tools to break people's head - well, ok, yes, they can be used that way, but it's not what they were invented for or the main reason why they are used (which is probably what OP is interested in).

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Maybe I'm being pedantic, but that's not *entirely* untrue... but I guess the analogy is mostly harmless. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you have an array, you can set up a pointer to point to an element of the array:

```
int a[10];
int *p = &a[0];
```

Here `p` points to the first element of `a`, which is `a[0]`. Now you can increment the pointer to point to the next element:

```
p++;
```

Now `p` points to the second element, `a[1]`. You can access the element here using `*p`. This is different from Java where you would have to use an integer index variable to access elements of an array.

Incrementing a pointer in C++ where that pointer does *not* point to an element of an array is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I understand this case, but wouldn't it encourage the situation of _undefined behavior_ and possibly segmentation faults?

Comment: Yep, with C++ you are responsible for avoiding programming errors such as access outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: Is there any other practical sense if we are not talking about an array? what if i increment a pointer of a simple int? why would i ever do that?

Comment: No, incrementing a pointer that points to anything *except* an array element is undefined behaviour. However, if you are doing something low level and not portable, then incrementing a pointer is usually nothing more than accessing the next thing in memory, whatever that may happen to be.

Comment: There are a few things that are, or can be treated as, an array; a string of text is, in fact, an array of characters. In some cases, a long int is treated as an array of bytes, though this can easily get you into trouble.

Comment: @greg Not true. It is defined behavior to increment a pointer one past the last element of an array.

Comment: @ThomasEding: Yes, that's what would happen if you increment it *while* it's pointing to the last element of the array. It's not valid to increment it further than one past the end, because at that point it's no longer pointing to an element of the array.

Comment: @GregHewgill: It does not matter what it points to. [expr.pre.incr] and [expr.post.incr] require _"The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type"_. The truthfulness of these conditions does not change if you point at an address past the end of an array. Merely _dereferencing_ that pointer would be undefined.

Comment: That tells you the _type_, but the _behaviour_ is described in 5.7 Additive operators [expr.add]. Specifically, 5.7/5 says that going anywhere outside the array except one-past-the-end is UB.

Comment: @Useless: 5.7/5 says no such thing. It merely states that overflow during the evaluation makes the result undefined. Which makes sense, since if a pointer operation overflows you can basically never expect something meaningful. On the contrary, 5.7/5 uses the wording _"point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the array object, **provided they exist**"_, which suggests that they might indeed not exist.

Comment: Last paragraph is: _If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise the behavior is undefined_. So, if the result is neither in the array nor one-past the end, you get UB.

Comment: @INdek That is precisely why you will often see it combined with something like `while(len > 0)`.

Comment: If a C++ module receives and `int*` from a C module, which has made it point to a single `int`, may the C++ module legitimately increment that pointer if it is not dereferenced?  For example, if one has a method to "output N integers" and needs to output exactly one, could one simply pass the address of an `int` along with a count of one?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Pointers can be used exactly the same as the traditional C++ iterator half-open interval `[begin, end)`.

Comment: But a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array is considered to be an array of single element thus incrementing it yields a off-end ponter. e.g: int `x = 5; int* ptr = &x; ++ptr;` `//ptr now is pointing past the last element. it is a valid pointer how ever only few operations it can support.` .

Answer (score 37):

Incrementing pointers is idiomatic C++, because pointer semantics reflect a fundamental aspect of the design philosophy behind the C++ standard library (based off of Alexander Stepanov's [**STL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library))

The important concept here, is that the STL is designed around containers, algorithms, and iterators.  Pointers are simply *iterators*.

Of course, the ability to increment (or add/subtract from) pointers goes back to C.  A lot of C-string manipulation algorithms can be written simply using pointer arithmetic.  Consider the following code:

```
char string1[4] = "abc";
char string2[4];
char* src = string1;
char* dest = string2;
while ((*dest++ = *src++));
```

This code uses pointer arithmetic to copy a null-terminated C-string.  The loop automatically terminates when it encounters the null.

With C++, pointer semantics are generalized to the concept of *iterators*.  Most standard C++ containers provide iterators, which can be accessed via the `begin` and `end` member functions.  Iterators behave like pointers, in that they can be incremented, dereferenced, and sometimes decremented or advanced.

To iterate over an `std::string`, we would say:

```
std::string s = "abcdef";
std::string::iterator it = s.begin();
for (; it != s.end(); ++it) std::cout << *it;
```

We increment the iterator just like we would increment a pointer to a plain C-string.  The reason this concept is powerful is because you can use templates to write functions that will work for *any* type of iterator that meets the necessary concept requirements.  And this is the power of the STL:

```
std::string s1 = "abcdef";
std::vector<char> buf;
std::copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(buf));
```

This code copies a string into a vector.  The `copy` function is a template that will work with *any* iterator that supports incrementing (which includes plain pointers).  We could use the same `copy` function on a plain C-string:

```
   const char* s1 = "abcdef";
   std::vector<char> buf;
   std::copy(s1, s1 + std::strlen(s1), std::back_inserter(buf));
```

We could use `copy` on an `std::map` or a `std::set` or *any* custom container that supports iterators.

Note that pointers are a specific type of iterator: *random access iterator*, which means they support incrementing, decrementing, and advancing with the `+` and `-` operator.  Other iterator types only support a subset of pointer semantics: a *bidirectional iterator* supports at least incrementing and decrementing; a *forward iterator* supports at least incrementing.  (All iterator types support dereferencing.)  The `copy` function requires an iterator that at least supports incrementing.

You can read about different iterator concepts [**here**](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html).

So, incrementing pointers is an idiomatic C++ way to iterate over a C-array, or access elements/offsets in a C-array.

Comment: Though I use pointers like in the first example, I never thought about it as an iterator, it makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: This is something of a back-formation of safe iterator behaviour from unsafe pointer behaviour; other languages with iterators tend to handle it differently.

Comment: _"The loop automatically terminates when it encounters the null."_ This is a terrifying idiom.

Comment: @CharlesWood, then I guess you must find C pretty terrifying

Comment: @CharlesWood: The alternative is to use the length of the string as the loop control variable, which means traversing the string twice (once to determine the length, and once to copy the characters). When you're running on a 1MHz PDP-7, that can really start to add up.

Comment: @TMN: interestingly, counted strings (as C++ `std::string` and strings in almost any other language) are almost often way more efficient (you avoid lots of O(n) in size determination, concatenations & co.). I always found C's choice of NUL-terminated strings particularly strange, especially given that it started being used in times when every clock cycle was precious.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Why? I think its a clever way no be able to traverse the array if you don't know how many elements it has.

Comment: @INdek: of course, but if you put the size separately you don't need to traverse the array just to get its length (and if you limit yourself e.g. to strings shorter than 65 KB you have only to pay for one byte more). Performing 4 `strcat` on a C string means that each time you have to walk to the end of the destination string, which makes the algorithm significantly slower for no gain. See e.g. [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: @MatteoItalia What a great article, i now have a much clearer perception of what involves C strings, i also have one more nightmare! Why didn't they redo strings in C-99?

Comment: @INdek: first of all, C and C++ try to avoid at all costs to introduce breaking changes - and I would say that altering the default behavior of string literals would be quite a modification. But most importantly, zero-terminated strings are just a convention (made easy to follow by the fact that string literals are zero-terminated by default and that the library functions expect them), nobody stops you from using counted strings in C - actually, several C libraries do use them (see e.g. OLE's BSTR).

Answer (score 18):

Pointer arithmetic is in C++ because it was in C. Pointer arithmetic is in C because it's a normal idiom in *assembler*.

There are plenty of systems where "increment register" is faster than "load constant value 1 and add to register". Moreover, quite a few systems let you do "load DWORD into A from address specified in register B, then add sizeof(DWORD) to B" in a single instruction. These days you might expect an optimising compiler to sort this out for you, but this wasn't really an option in 1973.

This is basically the same reason that C arrays aren't bounds-checked and C strings don't have a size embedded in them: the language was developed on a system where every byte and every instruction counted.